# Misplaced \noalign

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

Unfortunately I cannot solve the error with noalign on my own:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.12 ... & \centering{B} & \centering{C} \\ \hline

I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.
```

I already tried it with `\cline`, but this didn't work either. By searching the web I found out that in all cases `\\` at the end of the line is missing. However, I have a `\\` at the end of the line:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{40pt} p{60pt}|p{120pt}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|p{220pt}|}{\multirow{2}{220pt}{\centering{\textbf{Title}}}} \\
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} \\ \hline
\centering{A} & \centering{B} & \centering{C} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: I had the same error but under different circumstances. The reason in my case was that I had forgotten a `\\ ` at the end of a row before an `\hline`. Just in case it helps someone else!

Answer (score 40):

`\centering` does not take an argument so as you used it its scope reaches to the end of the cell, but it redefines `\\` to be a centred new line so you can use the unambiguous form of the array row separator: `\tabularnewline`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{40pt} p{60pt}|p{120pt}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|p{220pt}|}{\multirow{2}{220pt}{\centering \textbf{Title}}} \tabularnewline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} \\ \hline
\centering A & \centering B & \centering C \tabularnewline \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Title A B C]

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be caused by the `\centering` in the very last cell of your table. I do not know exactly why this fails, but if you centre `C` manually, the problem goes away.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{40pt} p{60pt}|p{120pt}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|p{220pt}|}{\multirow{2}{220pt}{\centering{\textbf{Title}}}} \\
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} \\ \hline
\centering{A} & \centering{B} & \hfil C \hfil \\ \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```