# Misplaced \noalign when centering tabularx cell

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I have a minimal LaTeX document like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X | X }
    \centering A & B \\ \hline
    1.0 & 2.0 \\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: A B 1.0 2.0]

I would like to center the table headers but left-align the columns. However, when I add `\centering` to the B header, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X | X }
    \centering A & \centering B \\ \hline
    1.0 & 2.0 \\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.8   \end{tabularx}

! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate

l.8   \end{tabularx}

! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.8   \end{tabularx}

! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate

l.8   \end{tabularx}

! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.8   \end{tabularx}

! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate

l.8   \end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Centering in `tabularx` and `X` columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89166/5764)

Comment: Not a duplicate, that's centering an entire column instead of individual cells.

Comment: So it's more general since the same procedure is applied to all cells within the same column. :-|

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109206/misplaced-noalign

Comment: Also related: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-tabcellalign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page 2 of the `tabularx` documentation says that you have to use `\arraybackslash` after `\centering` (or `\raggedright` or `\ragggedleft`). Use like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X | X }
    \centering\arraybackslash A & \centering\arraybackslash B \\ \hline
    1.0 & 2.0 \\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

LaTeX's text alignment commands redefine `\\` so that they don't mean “a new line in the table” anymore. The `\arraybackslash` command does `\let\\\tabularnewline` so that it will work again.

Alternatively, you can use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\` at the end of the first row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X | X }
    \centering A & \centering B \tabularnewline \hline
    1.0 & 2.0 \\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` for the column heads. Or load `makecell` and use its `thead` command (by default, its content is centred, both horizontally and vertically), which has the possibility to define a common formatting of all `thead`s arguments. Here is an example of both methods:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, xcolor}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{red}}

\begin{document}

  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X | X }
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} \\ \hline
    1.0 & 2.0 \\
  \end{tabularx}
\vspace{4ex}

  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X | X }
    \thead{A} & \thead{B} \\ \hline
    1.0 & 2.0 \\
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]